# C++ passing around vectors

Tags: c++

I'm newish to C++ (but not new to programming in general)

I am trying to call this getOption, and the error message is complaining that this call:

```
getOption(
        "What do you want to do?",
        std::vector<std::string>[
            "Add a person",
            "Delete a person",
            "Print database information",
            "Report average age",
            "List all names",
            "Exit"]);
```

doesn't match the following function definition:

```
int getOption(std::string prompt, std::vector<std::string> choices)
```

I tried searching SO, but I don't really understand what is going on enough to come up with keywords that will match already answered questions.

What concept of C++ am I missing here?

Comment: don't use the square brackets for vectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just screwing up the constructor syntax. Don't use brackets; use braces. (This will only work in C++11.)

Comment: Ah, that worked.  Why doesn't the compiler complain against square brackets?

Comment: Either it did, and you didn't understand the message, or there's some crazy way to interpret that sequence of characters that makes it valid syntax.

Comment: Error message:`Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
int getOption(std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>, std::vector<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,std::allocator<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>>>)` with the underline on the function call

Comment: Furthermore, if I pull the code creating the vector out of the function, it doesn't complain (except for the function call)

Answer (score 1):

use  braces instead. It's the initializer list in constructor. It only works in c++11.